# admin-on-rest custom routes redirecting to dashboard

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am trying to add a custom route to AOR that acts as a landing page for an email link. When I navigate to http://localhost:3000/random_page AOR changes the url to http://localhost:3000/random_page#/ and renders the Dashboard component instead of my RandomPage. I am probably missing something simple here but this is a barebones custom route example. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import RandomPage from './RandomPage'

export default [
    <Route exact path="/random_page" component={RandomPage} noLayout/>,
]
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { jsonServerRestClient, fetchUtils, Admin, Resource, Delete } from 'admin-on-rest';
import { LogList } from './components/LogList';
import { UserLogs } from './components/UserLogs';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard'
import authClient from './authClient'
import customRoutes from './customRoutes'

const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    options.headers.set('X-AUTH-TOKEN', localStorage.getItem('token'));
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Admin
        authClient={authClient}
        title = "Logs"
        restClient={jsonServerRestClient('http://localhost:3001/admin', httpClient)} 
        customRoutes={customRoutes}
        dashboard={Dashboard}
        >
        <Resource name="users" list={UserList} show={UserLogs}/>
        <Resource name="logs" list={LogList} remove={Delete} />
      </Admin>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should navigate to http://localhost:3000/#/random_page

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're looking for [catchAll](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#catchall) found under the `<Admin>` component in the docs. You can then parse out the information you need from the URL and handle accordingly.